# Uploading gzipped content to AWS S3 from command line.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I used to used s3cmd and then I had to upgrade it to version 1.5.0-alpha3. I have been unable to do a proper s3cmd sync with the header `--add-header="Content-Encoding: gzip"`

The command I use is

```
s3cmd --add-header="Content-Encoding: gzip" --add-header="Cache-Control:public, max-age=86400" --add-header='Content-Type: application/javascript' --recursive put local remote_S3_bucket
```

The headers are uploaded but the zipped files somehow get unzipped. I have tried with/without the `--no-preserve` flag and several other permutations of the headers.

I have also tried doing the same with the [aws s3 cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) but there does not seem to be a way to add the `"Content-Encoding: gzip"` headers with this tool.

What tool (and version and from which source i.e os package manager, github) should one use as of today to sync gzipped files successfully?

Answer (score 3):

They are "somehow" getting automatically unzipped by your user agent when you download them... because that's what is *supposed* to happen when you store gzipped content with proper headers, like those... check the size of the file in the AWS console and I expect you will find that what you stored is smaller than what you downloaded.

When you store gzipped content with `Content-Encoding: gzip` you also drop the .gz extension because what is going to end up downloaded is no longer gzipped when handed to the end user because the browser, or wget, etc. content-un-encodes it, if you will.

If you just want to put the .gz file out there for download as a .gz file, don't set Content-Encoding.

Comment: I want to put gz files out there for downloading as non-gzip. EG. js and css files. That process works fine. The only part that is broken is the s3 command line tool that seems to mess up uploads with the `content-encoding:gzip` header

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [Minio Client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc)

A simple operation like below should work.

```
$ mc cat  | gzip - | mc pipe s3/bucket/file
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)